# multiple $(document).ready and $(window).load in $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got 2 questions. First of all, this is not my work. I'm currently looking at somebody else's JavaScript files. I can't give the exact code but I can show what I'm wondering.

In the JavaScript files I see a lot of `$(document).ready(function(){});`. I know what `$(document).ready` does, the callback function will be called when the DOM tree is loaded. Is there any reason why somebody would use more than one `$(document).ready` callback? I don't get the point.

Also, another thing I saw was a `$(window).load` inside a `$(document).ready`, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
         //...
    });
});
```

From what I know, `$(window).load()` is called when everything of a page is loaded, like assets and images etc. I would think `$(window).load()` is the last thing called, after `$(document).ready`. Is there any time where `$(window).load` is called BEFORE `$(document).ready` and is there any reason why you would put a `$(window).load` inside a `$(document).ready`?

Comment: Just looks like it was written by someone who didn't know what they were doing

Comment: It was a trainee AFAIK, but I have no clue who wrote it. It was written at the time I was back in school so I have no clue. But yeah, looks like it, but I'm just asking to be 100% sure.

Comment: @Joshua Bakker what you you have written regarding to $(document).write and $(window).load() is perfentibly acceptibe, and it is correct may be it was written by someone who didn't have and idea of whats going on..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, jQuery grants that `ready` event will be called before `load`. Even in IE8- (where `DOMContentLoaded` is not supported) it works in that way. But let's look at the following code:

```
<!doctype html>

<title>Ready vs load test</title>

<style>body {white-space: pre}</style>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<script>
  ~function () {
    function log(msg) {
      document.body.innerHTML += msg + "\n";
    }

    function handler(msg) {
      return function () {
        log(msg);
      }
    }

    $(window).load(handler("5. load #1"));
    $(document).ready(handler("1. ready #2"));
    $(window).load(handler("6. load #3"));
    $(document).ready(handler("2. ready #4"));
    $(document).ready(function () {
      log("3. ready #5");
      $(window).load(handler("8. load #6"));
    });
    $(document).ready(handler("4. ready #7"));
    $(window).load(handler("7. load #8"));
  }();
</script>
```

The result is

```
1. ready #2
2. ready #4
3. ready #5
4. ready #7
5. load #1
6. load #3
7. load #8
8. load #6
```

Look at lines 7 and 8. The `load` handled attached from `ready` event is the last one. So by using this way we can ensure that all previously added (during scripts parsing and exection) `load` handlers have already been called.

> so using `$(window).load` outside the `$(document).ready` and inside doesn't change that much from how it'd affect how stuff work?

Actually it can affect script execution. The first version works and the second doesn't:

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).load(function () {
      $.magic.value = 12;
    });
  });
</script>

<script>
  $(window).load(function () {
    $.magic = {};
  });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  });

  $(window).load(function () {
    $.magic.value = 12;
  });
</script>

<script>
  $(window).load(function () {
    $.magic = {};
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The question is if you really still have to look at IE8-. I'd say it's easy to upgrade and people should.

Comment: @JoshuaBakker, I found the difference. Give me a minute to update an answer.

Comment: Okay, so using `$(window).load` outside the `$(document).ready` and inside doesn't change that much from how it'd affect how stuff work?

Comment: Thanks for the test as well, seems like the last person who worked on it made it a big mess.

Comment: I understand now. It'll be done in the correct order, and `$(window).load` inside `$(document).ready` will be done last. Thanks for the good examples. Cheers! Now I see I have a lot of code to clean up :-)

Comment: @JoshuaBakker, not the last, but in order of subscription.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready kicks in when all nodes of the DOM have been loaded but not necessarily their content, that's what's $(window).load is for, e.g. an img-ele can be present, yet it's content – the image – hasn't been loaded.

So, you're right, use each listener only once and don't nest them.

Comment: I know that. But I just wanted to make sure that my statement about that `$(window).load` won't be called BEFORE `$(document).ready`.